# Two different onClick for a different Dialog for DatePicker

Tags: android, datepicker

I have two different edittext for `reservation` and `return` and I want it to have a different Date Picker but when I'm over riding a method it says `Method does not override method from its super class` here is my code.

```
public class TransactionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etResDate, etReturnDate ;
    Button btnRent;
    int year_x,month_x,day_x;
    int year_x1,month_x1,day_x1;
    int hour_x,minute_x;

    static final int DIALOG_ID = 0;
    static final int DIALOG_ID1 = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transaction);
        showDialogOnButtonClick();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        year_x = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month_x = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day_x = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        year_x1 = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month_x1 = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day_x1 = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        etResDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etResDate);
        etReturnDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etReturnDate);
    }

    public void showDialogOnButtonClick() {
        etResDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etResDate);
        etReturnDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etReturnDate);

        etResDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        etReturnDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DIALOG_ID1);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        if(id == DIALOG_ID){
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, dplistener, year_x,month_x,day_x);
        }
        else if (id == DIALOG_ID1){
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, dplistener1, year_x1, month_x1, day_x1);
        }
      return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dplistener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            year_x = year;
            month_x = monthOfYear + 1;
            day_x = dayOfMonth;
            etResDate.setText(month_x + "/" +  day_x + "/" + year_x);
        }

    };
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dplistener1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year1, int monthOfYear1, int dayOfMonth1) {
            year_x1 = year1;
            month_x1 = monthOfYear1 + 1;
            day_x1 = dayOfMonth1;
            etReturnDate.setText(month_x1 + "/" +  day_x1 + "/" + year_x1);
        }
    };


}
```

Thanks for the help guys. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that correct is `onCreateDialog()` and not `onCreateDialog1()`

Maybe, you just need to delete `onCreateDialog1()` and update your `onCreateDialog()` as follows:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    if(id == DIALOG_ID){
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dplistener, year_x,month_x,day_x);
    else if (id == DIALOG_ID1) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dplistener1, year_x, month_x, day_x);
    }
    return null;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Another error is here:

```
static final int DIALOG_ID = 0;
static final int DIALOG_ID1 = 0;
```

Both dialogs has the SAME ID. You must set `DIALOG_ID1 = 1`;

Comment: THANK YOU SIR! IT DID THE TRICK!! YOU'RE THE BEST! :) THANKS AGAIN SIR :)

Comment: @B.Dee I'm glad I could help you. Best Regards!